# Passing JVM parameter having space charater in a File

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I am having an error `"Error: Could not find or load main class %l"",` when running run.sh script, I have a work around solution that replacing space char between `"%h %l"` with other one such as "%h-%l".

interesting part is that when I run the exact path (COMMAND_PATH) on command line everything is fine.
It seems that passing a JVM parameter having space character in a file cause a problem.

Do you have any solution and advice for this one?

## JVM parameter stored in app.jvm.properties file

-Dserver.tomcat.access-log-pattern="%h %l"

```
---run.sh---

JVM_OPTIONS=`tr '\n' ' ' < ${APP_HOME}/bin/app.jvm.properties`
COMMAND_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JVM_OPTIONS} -jar APP.jar" 
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JVM_OPTIONS} -jar APP.jar
```

Comment: In the `JVM_OPTIONS` are there the delimiters (`"`) still preserved? The error message makes me think that the delimiters are not in place. Please do an `echo ${JVM_OPTIONS}` to check the parameters

Comment: When using `COMMAND_PATH` on the command line works fine, why don’t you try using `COMMAND_PATH` in the script too? The difference is obvious, when defining `COMMAND_PATH` you are using double quotes, in the subsequent line, you don’t, but why do you define the variable and don’t use it then?

Comment: @UwePlonus yes I am sure it exists, I can execute printed full command path over comman line manually.

Comment: @Holger I have also tried to run COMMAND_PATH in script but having same error.

Comment: Then why does it work on the command line? Is it truly the same shell?

Comment: in file #!/bin/bash is at the top of the run.sh file , I have checked that echo $0
-bash,  using bash shell

Comment: space usage shouldnot be used in bash i think, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258727/spaces-in-variable-assignments-in-shell-scripts

Comment: You should be able to change app.jvm.properties to use single quotes: -Dserver.tomcat.access-log-pattern='%h %l'. alternatively, using \" around the ${JVM_OPTIONS} in COMMAND_PATH, and using " around ${JVM_OPTIONS} in the last line should work.

Comment: @JonahBenton . thanks your advice, all have been tested but does not solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, do this- with app.jvm.properties as described in the question, change run.sh as follows- 1) comment out the last line 2) add a subsequent line that says: eval $COMMAND_PATH